# Regex Preg Replace HTML

Tags: php, regex

Please consider the following paragraph...

```
{{if|service_name=Service}}
  Hello this is the Service text
{{endif}}
```

This is the format that I allow my users to place custom conditional variables inside contract text. This means that if the service matches "Service", the text will show. I achieve this replacement functionality with the following....

```
$text = preg_replace("/{{if\|service_name=$service}}\s*(.*?)\R{{endif}}/s", "$1", $text);
```

This works great, right up until CKeditor is used on the contract text field, and my clients new lines are wrapped in `<p>` tags.

So the above works, but this does not..,

```
<p>{{if|service_name=Service}}</p>

<p>Hello this is the Service text</p>

<p>{{endif}}</p>
```

I have placed an example here... https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/pEE

Can anyone shed some light on my issue?

Comment: 1) Use another regex tester to test multiline strings as whole strings. 2) Remove `\R` since there is no line break between `<p>` and `{{endif}}` 3) Do not use `U` modifier that switches greediness. See https://regex101.com/r/kKt2M6/1

Comment: So what is the result you expect? Note that you cannot "skip" the `<p>` tags when matching, you will have to remove them with some `str_replace(['<p>', '</p>'], '', $res)` or similar option (or `strip_tags`) after extraction.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. It was the \R newline that was tripping it up. Please add as an answer and I will accept  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\R` construct matches any line break sequence, and there is no line break between  `<p>` and `{{endif}}`.

Your regex may be quick-fixed as

```
'~{{if\|service_name=Service}}\s*(.*?)\s*{{endif}}~s'
                                      ^^^
```

The `\s*` will match any amount of any whitespace (add `u` modifier after/before `s` if you may have any Unicode whitespace in the string).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kKt2M6/2).

Answer (score 0):

Turn it off then, simple!

```
CKEDITOR.config.autoParagraph = false;
```

https://docs-old.ckeditor.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.autoParagraph

Comment: Nope, need the editor for all sorts of formatting options.

Comment: it's just auto paragraphs you're turning off, not all formatting, give it a try at least

Comment: Yeah that would be good, but the chances are they are going to use all sorts of other html in these areas, unordered lists, tables etc. I need something a bit more resilient. Thanks though

Comment: That should be fine though, I thought it was only HTML generated by CKEditor that the user did not actually input that you were trying to get rid of, I would presume any markup the user adds would be fine. Why not just try it?